# Double definition of internal function in stdio.h

Tags: c++, linker, mingw

*Hello World* compiles neatly. Narrowed it down to this:

```
#include <string>

int main () {
    string foo = std::to_string (1);
    return 0;
}
```

As it turns out, CodeBlocks has trouble parsing this particular error, so I couldn't find it in full originally. It also doesn't compile using g++ from the command line:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -o test.exe main.cpp
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libmingwex.a(vsnprintf.o):(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `vsnprintf'; C:\Users\inaki\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMZNor2.o:main.cpp:(.text$vsnprintf[_vsnprintf]+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

OnlineGDB compiles it no problem. What's going on here?

Comment: `iostream` or something else is including `stdio.h`. What's the exact error and the problem code?

Comment: You are looking at context information about a previous error. Read the generated errors from top to bottom. The first error lines are usually the most relevant.

Comment: Do you mean that you get a build *error*, not that the linker actually crashes? When asking about build errors, *always* show the code that causes the error (preferably in the form of a [mcve]), and copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build output into the question itself. Also please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I don't recall that I have ever in my life seen a linker crash and I have compiled `c` code for over 30 years and `c++` for 25+. I don't think the linker crashes from your code. With that said no one can help unless you better explain what you are talking about and include a minimal example with the exact text of the error messages.

Comment: That's your compiler telling you about an error, not the linker crashing.

Comment: Does a "Hello World" application build when you use`printf`? Does it build when you use `cout` instead of `printf`? Are you compilng with gcc or g++ at the command line or are you using an IDE? Is there any chance that you have more than 1 version of `mingw` installed?

Comment: Hopefully, I've addressed all your concerns.

Comment: Just a couple of small things: How was the object file `obj\Debug\main.o` created? What flags was used when building it? And for a perfect [mcve], we should really be able to copy-paste it and try to build it ourselves and be able to replicate the exact problem you have, so please also tell us what environment you're working in? Are you using an IDE to build? Which one? Which version? How have you configured your build settings?

Comment: Accessing the compiler directly gives the same error, so it's not an IDE problem. Main function added to example. Now the build attempt is from the code, rather than the object file.

Comment: I suspect this is not yet minimal, and it's just the `std::to_string`. But if this **is** minimal, it would be good to say so explicitly. E.g. does the error go away if you comment out the if-statement?

Comment: Seems like it is. I've reduced the example.